# Mendeley is encrypting my data on my hard disk with a key only available to them: can I ask for unencrypted data under GDPR?

Tags: gdpr, data-protection, data-storage, encryption, data

I use [Mendeley Desktop](https://www.mendeley.com/download-desktop-new/) to manage my bibliography. Now I want to switch to [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/).

Zotero used to be able to import the Mandeley's database. However, Mendeley 1.19 encrypted my data on my HDD with a key that only Elsevier has. See [here](https://www.zotero.org/support/kb/mendeley_import):

> Mendeley 1.19 and later have begun encrypting the local database,
> making it unreadable by Zotero and other standard database tools.
> Elsevier made this change a few months after Zotero publicly announced
> work on an importer, despite having long touted the openness of its
> database format as a guarantee against lock-in and explaining in its
> documentation that the database could be accessed using standard
> tools.

Mendeley [claims](https://twitter.com/mendeley_com/status/1006916616377036801) that they were compelled to do so by GDPR:

> We have encrypted users’ databases to comply with GDPR. You can still
> export your libraries to get data locally and/or import into another
> reference manager.

They also claim that I can export my data, but this is not true. Mendeley would only export basically a list of DOIs, and I am losing all the organization in folders it took me months to make.

I have zillions of articles: I can't afford to have them all in one folder in Zotero.

People are trying to [break the encryption](https://eighty-twenty.org/2018/06/13/mendeley-encrypted-db) but I am not able to do that.

1. Can I ask them to provide me with a copy of the unencrypted database under [art. 20.1 of GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-20-gdpr/)?
2. Can I ask them to send the data directly to Zotero under article 20.2 of GDPR?

Comment: What personal data of yours do they have?

Comment: @DaleM Mendeley Desktop is a bibliography manager. So they basically have a list of my favourite scientific articles, together with articles metadata (authors, title, journal, etc.) and an attached PDF file with the actual article for each entry of the list

Comment: I don’t see how a list of academic articles is personal data as defined in GDPR

Comment: @DaleM Well (1) They encrypted the database [to comply with GDPR](https://twitter.com/mendeley_com/status/1006916616377036801). So they themselves must deem this database as personal data (2) The list contains my preferences for scientific fields / article in that field, and is an information related to me, an identified natural person. No?

Comment: @DaleM If a list of my favourite scientific articles is not personal data, is a list of your favourite books not personal data as well? So that if a user's come in my site, and inputs on my system that his favourite book is Mein Kampf, I can go all over the social networks and publish that <NAME> <SURNAME> reads that book because that is not personal data?